# Difference between "focus" and "concentration"

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context, nouns

What is the difference between *focus* and *concentration* in the following context?

> High-flow activities require focus and concentration; your mind is actively engaged in what you are doing.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: the context: High-flow activities require focus and concentration;
your mind is actively engaged in what you are doing.

Comment: I'm new comer in this site.sorry,I don't know some rules.

Comment: I know their meaning.The problem is, when it comes to Persian language they have almost the same meaning. I should add something more to their meaning.

Comment: Hi Shakiba. You should go to a dictionary site, like [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com) and look up both words. That should show the differences to you. If you still are unsure, come back and edit your question explaining how the research you have done has left you unsure. Be sure to explain what it is about the definitions that has created this confusion. Happy searching!

Comment: @MattЭллен  Dictionaries typically define the two words almost synonymously and even cross reference them! In actual use, the words are very often used interchangeably in non-technical writing.

Comment: @Kris - I doubt that. You can't concentrate your camera, and you don't dilute your focus with water.

Comment: @MattЭллен Which is why I concluded with "in non-technical writing"

Comment: @Kris — non-technical people talk about focusing their cameras. Maybe concentration is a technical term, but it's on the side of all squash bottles. None the less, there are plenty of non-technical uses for each word that are not synonymous.

Comment: @Matt: Your argument is spurious. You might as well say that “left” and “right” aren’t opposites because the past participle of “leave” has nothing to do with correctness or privilege. This question is about mental processes, not optics or chemistry.

Comment: @Scott I started that argument before the context was added.

Comment: The answers given are effective, well done. Now, how about a joke answer? Focus brings clarity, while concentration brings density :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, *focus*                                                                                                                   relates to the (better definition of) lateral extent (breadth/ range/ coverage), while concentration is about depth.

In other words, as you focus more and more, your attention is confined to a smaller and smaller area.  When you concentrate on something, the depth of your attention is greater.

In practical terms, it is possible to visualize the difference in some instances, while in others it may be merely a matter of opinion.

***focus*** (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/focus) **1** *the centre of interest or activity*

However, dictionaries also define *focus* somewhat synonymous with *concentrate*, at least in literary use.

Comment: I disagree. You're trying to create a spurious "technical" distinction between the two words *in OP's context*. Per comments to the question, there are plenty of "non-technical" contexts where the words aren't at all interchangeable, but (technical or not) this isn't one of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "... while in others it may be merely a matter of opinion." :)

Comment: Hmm. Your "technical" definitions of *focus* and *concentration* seem a bit arbitrary to me. You could just as easily reverse the particular qualities you've chosen to focus/concentrate on for each word. The oxforddictionaries entry is largely irrelevant, in that it just shows that the two words can't be used interchangeably in *all* contexts (we can speak of the *focus of a discussion*, but not the *concentration of the discussion*).

Answer (score 6):

Quite possibly someone will provide an answer attempting to show how *focus **and** concentration* somehow means something more than either word on its own.

So far as I'm concerned, in OP's specific context it's just tautological repetition for the sake of emphasis. This is perfectly normal in English, and [in no way, shape, or form](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_no_way,_shape,_or_form) is it a "defect".

Comment: You mean that these words do not have any connotations in their meaning?

Comment: @Shakiba r.abadi: Of course they have other meanings in other contexts that are *not* equivalent. The concentration of an acid has nothing to do with focus, for example. But in your context (metaphoric **mental** *focus/concentration*) they're just different words for the same thing - "undivided close attention".

Comment: (+1) for *tautological repetition for the sake of emphasis*.

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @Shakiba r.abadi: As I understand it, your native language is Persian, not English. I don't know Persian, but I'd have thought *all* languages have certain word-pairs which *in certain contexts* both have the same meaning. Even if you can find a few native English speakers who claim *focus* and *concentration* actually convey different meanings in your example, that won't change the fact that for everyone else they are the same. Given you're the one asking the question, I don't see what it "means" for you to disagree with the answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't disagree. I just say when in the context, we have both of these words, so they don't have the same meaning. Do they?Sometimes In Persian language, unfortunately, there is just one meaning for a bunch of words.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, as @FumbleFingers says, *focus* and *concentration* mean pretty much the same thing.

In slightly different contexts, however, *focus* (as a noun) may also be used to designate the **object** of the action. This is infrequently encountered with *concentration*, except in the academic *area of concentration*.

*Concentration*, on the other hand, is somewhat more likely to be used when the writer wants to emphasize the **action** itself, or the effort expended.

And wider afield, of course, usage is still more distinct: you are very unlikely to hear of a lens bringing light rays to a *concentration*, or of enemies of the state being imprisoned in a *focus* camp!

Answer (score 3):

Focus is to narrow down your attention to something, concentration is to keep the focus maintained

Comment: Agreed. When I hear "concentrate", I imagine distractions all around that I have to avoid thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of mental activity:

Focus: Allocate mental resources to a particular task -- e.g. to read this line or that paragraph or that book

(Pure) Concentration : Allocation of mental resources to a particular task over the duration of (uninterrupted) time that is required to execute the task.

Focus is like the smallest unit of Concentration. Concentration occurs when contiguous units of focus are allocated to execute the task.

The main difference : Concentration is required to execute the task, focus is require to direct attention to the task

Not staying focus, simply means the lack of concentration